# How to allow debian user to run a command as in a specific group using sudo?

Tags: sudo, logs, group

I'm trying to allow users to read log files. In `debian` users in group `adm` is allows to read many log files. (Ref : https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups)

So my plan is to use sudo and allow users to run commands like `ail, less, more` on log files as they in `adm` group.

My try was something like below and it didn't work.
User `website` is the account I have hosted my website.
Users `user1`, `user2` are the developers who work on website and trying to look at log files.

> Config: user1 ALL=(website:adm) /bin/tail /var/www/error.log
>
> command: sudo -u website tail /var/www/error.log

That I did wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `sudo` to change groups:

```
sudo -g adm tail /var/www/error.log
```

(as one of the appropriate users).

Alternatively, you could just add the users to the `adm` group, it's only used for log files in Debian nowadays...